# Cannot connect to PCI ethernet with r8168 driver on Ubuntu 18.04 w/kernel 4.15.0-76-generic

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I saw that the default driver was r8169 on my 18.04 install of Ubuntu.

I then followed this guide (https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/) which suggested

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

This was successful but after rebooting, still no ethernet connection.

```
sara@sara-Aspire-V5-591G:/usr/lib$ dkms status
r8168, 8.045.08, 4.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed

sara@sara-Aspire-V5-591G:/usr/lib$ modinfo r8168 | grep -i version
version:        8.045.08-NAPI
srcversion:     45361C7A45067DE67257C08
```

If I do ifconfig, I see

```
enp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:ab:3a:2c:4b:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 76299  bytes 7139057 (7.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 894  bytes 280187 (280.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 126  base 0x5000
```

If I do

```
sara@sara-Aspire-V5-591G:/usr/lib$ ethtool enp8s0
Settings for enp8s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

sara@sara-Aspire-V5-591G:/usr/lib$ sudo ethtool -S enp8s0
[sudo] password for sara: 
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 894
     rx_packets: 79934
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 0
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 0
     broadcast: 76397
     multicast: 3537
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0
```

Any help?

Comment: So remove it by `sudo apt purge r8168-dkms`.

Comment: But isn’t it the right driver?

Comment: The right driver is the in-tree `r8169`. You install an alternative if there is a problem with it.